# Changing dates into Quarter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a `"dates"` column in a dataframe called new_data.
The dates are in the format 2019-08-01. I just want to change all the dates into just `'Q1'`, `'Q2'` etc..

I tried this looping through rows and replace, no luck

```py
qtwo_startdate = pd.to_datetime("2019-03-30").date()
qtwo_enddate = pd.to_datetime("2019-07-1").date()

for i, row in new_data["dates"]:
    if i[qtwo_startdate:qtwo_enddate]:
        new_data.replace(i, "Q2")
```

I just the the dates column to say either `'Q1'`, `'Q2'`, etc...

> > TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable datetime.date object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change to `datetime` and get the `quarter` attribute:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['2018-01-01']], columns=['Date'])
df['Quarter'] = 'Q'+pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.quarter.astype(str)
```

Output

```py
    Date        Quarter
0   2018-01-01  Q1
```